# Hebrew encoding from CSV to Eclipse to MySql comes as garbage

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, character-encoding

I have a CSV file with Hebrew characters. When I open it in TextEdit, on my Mac, I can see the Hebrew just fine.

I bring it into my Java code using a scanner, while encoding it to UTF-8:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + fileName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```

Then I parse, and send it to the MySql database using Hibernate:

```
for(int i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

    String elem = elements[i];
    String[] client = elem.split(",");

    for(int j=0; j<client.length; j++) {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.setFirstName(client[j]);
        System.out.println(client[j]);
        DatastoreManager.persist(c);
    }
}
```

Both the printout in the Eclipse consol, and the entry into MySql come as ?????.

Searching for solutions I tried converting the string to bytes:

```
byte[] ptext = client[j].getBytes("UTF8");
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

and I converted the MySql table to Character Set UTF-8 Unicode and Collation utf8mb4_general_ci.

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your Eclipse console doesn't support UTF-8 character encoding.

Comment: What's the encoding of the original file?

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at this article, which gives a general understanding encoding http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Luiggi, how do I change it to have the console support UTF-8? Mark, I'm not sure, how do I check it? The file is too large for Excel to open itand so I can only view it using TextEdit.

Comment: Use file -I {filename} in mac to check encoding.

Comment: OK I get the Hebrew on my console thanks to this here: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/
But "get info" on the mac doesn't bring up encoding information for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use file -I {filename} in mac to check encoding.
Encoding that you get change in:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```

Now I suppose that you see properly encoded characters in eclipse.

Since you are using Hibernate and MySql You should add following to your hibernate configuration:

```
app_persistance.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabase?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
app_persistance.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf8
app_persistance.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf8
app_persistance.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

Comment: Thanks, adding useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8 did it.

Comment: what about file -I {filename} in mac to check encoding.

Comment: Yes, it is utf-8. Thanks :)